# Catching subscribe / subscribe_private within a controller using WebsocketRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm using Rails 4.1.0 with Thin, and my Gemfile reads "gem 'websocket-rails'".

So far so good, i've been able to use channels and trigger actions properly on both sides. However, i'm trying to get some kind of notification (:subscribe / :subscribe_private) when a client socket tries to join a channel (Let it be private or public, it doesn't change the problem).

Basically, i see that lib/websocket_rails/internal_event.rb from the websocket-rails gem is handling this flow, but when i do the same from my event routing file, it never gets called at all, while all my more 'regular' actions work.

```
subscribe :subscribe, :to => MessagesController, :with_method => :test
subscribe :unsubscribe, :to => MessagesController, :with_method => :test
```

Is there any sort of trick to get this working, e.g. a specific version of WSR to use, or something else? I've tried using different branches of the gem without joy so far.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of downvoting me, please tell me why is this question worth downvoting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i actually found the answer to this question. It's very odd, in fact those two events (:subscribe / :subscribe_private) are only being used when surrounded by the :websocket_rails namespace.

So this doesn't work:

```
WebsocketRails::EventMap.describe do
  subscribe   :subscribe,           to: WebsocketMessagesController,  with_method: :subscribe
  subscribe   :subscribe_private,   to: WebsocketMessagesController,  with_method: :subscribe_private
  subscribe   :client_connected,    to: WebsocketMessagesController,  with_method: :client_connected
  subscribe   :index,               to: WebsocketMessagesController,  with_method: :index
  subscribe   :create,              to: WebsocketMessagesController,  with_method: :create
end
```

While this does:

```
WebsocketRails::EventMap.describe do
  namespace :websocket_rails do
    subscribe   :subscribe,           to: WebsocketMessagesController,  with_method: :subscribe
    subscribe   :subscribe_private,   to: WebsocketMessagesController,  with_method: :subscribe_private
  end
  subscribe   :client_connected,    to: WebsocketMessagesController,  with_method: :client_connected
  subscribe   :index,               to: WebsocketMessagesController,  with_method: :index
  subscribe   :create,              to: WebsocketMessagesController,  with_method: :create
end
```